# Resize image, issues with overlaying pixel

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I'm trying to write a function which can scale image up and down with a scale factor like 1.5 or 0.5. When I scale down the image will appear correct on the screen when I scale up there is some kind of screen overlay on the image. See images below
[image: Scale up]

[image: Scale down]

This is the code I wrote:

```
public static void ResizeImage(Bitmap inputImage, double scale)
{
    int maxWidth = (int) (scale * inputImage.Width);
    int maxHeight = (int) (scale * inputImage.Height);


    Bitmap scaledImage = new Bitmap(maxWidth, maxHeight); 
    for(int x = 0; x < inputImage.Width; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < inputImage.Height; y++)
        {
            //Gets current Pixel
            Color pixel = inputImage.GetPixel(x, y);

            //Calucalte new position Pixel
            int newPixelX = (int) (Math.Floor(x * scale));
            int newPixelY = (int) (Math.Floor(y * scale));

            //Sets pixel in new image
            scaledImage.SetPixel(newPixelX, newPixelY, pixel); 
        }
    }
    DrawImage(Bitmap2colorm(scaledImage)); 
}
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem and can someone give me an explaintion why this is happening?

Comment: Why don't you start with a 2x2 image with a scale of 2.5 and inspect your new X and Y coordinates for each pixel?

Comment: @CodeCaster If I try that there are a lot of extra white pixels. How to continue from that

Comment: Why don't you use some internal rescale methods? *(e.g. `DrawImage`)* It is many times faster and better to use. `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` are really slow.

Comment: Every-time someone uses `GetPixel` `SetPixel` something beautiful in the world dies a slow painful death

Comment: You're setting one pixel per source pixel. If you're scaling up, this will lead to gaps between the pixels. If you're scaling down, you're overwriting pixels multiple times. Do you want to write your own scaling algorithm, or don't you know about existing ones?

Comment: @CodeCaster I understand. I'm trying to implement the nearest neighbour interpolation algorithm

Comment: @Sander Bakker  Are you implementing your own Interpolation algorithm for study purposes? Or the default implementation of [`InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-interpolation-mode-to-control-image-quality-during-scaling) does not satisfy some requirement?